# How to query Model using SQLAlchemy by ID

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

There are two tables: "User" and "Project" defined as follows:

```
create table user (
  id integer primary key autoincrement
);

create table project (
  id integer primary key autoincrement,
  user_id integer
);
```

And the third table is used to map users to projects ids:

```
create table users_to_projects_table (
  user_id integer,
  project_id integer
);
```

In Python I declare the relation table first:

```
users_to_projects_table = db.Table('users_to_projects_table',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('project_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.id'))
)
```

Then I proceed by creating classes for `Project` and `User` tables:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    projects = db.relationship('Project', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')


class Project(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    _users = db.relationship('User', secondary=users_to_projects_table, backref=db.backref('users_to_projects_backref', lazy='dynamic'))

    @property
    def users(self):
        return self._users

    @users.setter
    def users(self, user_ids):
        self._users = [User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).one() for user_id in user_ids]
```

Now when it is all done I go ahead and create `user`:

```
user = User()
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

Next I create the `project` by passing it `user.id` as an argument:

```
project = Project( users=[user.id] )
db.session.add(project)
db.session.commit()
```

Everything looks good. I can see that both `user` and `project` were written to database. And that the `users_to_projects_table` was properly updated with both project_id and associated with it user_id.

Question: Now with `users_to_projects_table` "knowing" which user_id corresponds to which `project_id` how do I query which users are linked to which Project?
The command below fails with `InvalidRequestError`:

```
project_id = 1
User.projects.query.filter_by(project_id=project_id)
```

Error is below:

```
InvalidRequestError: Entity '<class '_app.User'>' has no property 'project_id'
```

What needs to be changed in order make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `secondary=users_to_projects_table` on the `projects` relationship.

A possible query would be `User.query.filter(User.projects.any(id=project_id))`, although it would probably be better to use a join.

A potentially faster (albeit longer) query using a join:

```
User.query.select_from(User).join(users_to_projects_table).join(Project).filter(Project.id==project_id
```

Comment: Thanks! The second command works well after appending `.all()` to its tail: `User.query.select_from(User).join(users_to_projects_table).join(Project).filter(Project.id==project_id).all()`

Comment: The first command you suggested works as well. Posting it here in its full form: `projects = db.relationship('Project', backref='user', lazy='dynamic', secondary=users_to_projects_table)`

Comment: And the querying command would be then: `User.query.filter(User.projects.any(id=project_‌​id)).all()` Thanks again!